# How to mock an inner function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Currently I am writing codes to test controller, which needs to call model. To avoid side effects on testing, I need to mock model. However, model is written in a quite complex way as it uses inner function as a constructor. I have tried different way, but still fails to achieve the purpose.

models/mondayModel.js

```
var mondayModel = function() {
  function fnA (req, callback) { 
   ...


  }
  function fnB (req, callback) { }
  function fnC (req, callback) { }
  function fnD (req, callback) { }
  return {
    fnA: fnA,
    fnB: fnB,
    fnC: fnC,
    fnD: fnD
  }
}

module.exports = mondayModel
```

controller/boxController.js

```
var MondayModel = require('../models/mondayModel');


function transfer(req, res, next) {
   ...
   var mondayModel = new MondayModel();
   mondayModel.fnA(req, payload, function(error, result) {
   ...
   }
}
```

boxController-test.jest

```
let boxController = null

describe('money tracker', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {        
        jest.mock('../../../../models/mondayBox',
            () => ({
              mondayBox: {
                fnA: jest.fn(),
                fnB: jest.fn(),
                fnC: jest.fn(),
                fnD: jest.fn()
            }
        }))    
    )
        boxController = require('../controllers/boxController')
    })

    test('success case', done => {
       const req = {}
       const payload = {}
       boxController.transfer(req, payload, (cbErr, cbRes) => {expect(cbRes).toBe('OK')
    }
}
```

But it gave `TypeError: mondayModel is not a constructor`

May I know that how to solve this mock (inner) function?
Thanks

Comment: where are you calling `new mondayModel()`?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Sorry, updated, it is in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think the `jest.mock` should be placed in the top. It will be hoisted to the top, but I don't know what would happen if placed inside another function.

And, you should pass a function, that return a newable

```
const model = require('../mondayModel');

jest.mock('../../../../models/mondayBox', () => function Model() {
  return {
    fnA: jest.fn(),
    fnB: jest.fn(),
    fnC: jest.fn(),
    fnD: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```

in your case,

```
const MondayModel = require('../mondayModel');
var mondayModel = new MondayModel();
```

is essentially

```
const MondayModel = {
  mondayBox: {
    fnA: jest.fn(),
    fnB: jest.fn(),
    fnC: jest.fn(),
    fnD: jest.fn()
  },
};
var mondayModel = new MondayModel();
```

you can try to console log it

Comment: I follow the way you said, but now mondayModel.transfer is not a function. But now it mocks success. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Noted that `the arrow function` can not be called as a constructor. The following snippet will explain your situation.

```js
var mondayModel = function () {
}

var mondayModelArrow = () => {} 
try {
  new mondayModel() // sucessfully
  new mondayModelArrow() // will throw exception
}
catch(e){
  console.error(e.stack)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. It's not a constructor. Just drop the `new`.

```
var mondayModel = MondayModel();
```

Or if you insist on making it a constructor, you can change the MondayModel like so and continue using `new`.

```
var mondayModel = function() {
  this.fnA = function (req, callback) { ... }
  this.fnB = function (req, callback) { ... }
  this.fnC = function (req, callback) { ... }
  this.fnD = function (req, callback) { ... }
}
```

Comment: But I think I should not change the original model and controller function. Original source codes currently work fine. I only need to mock model, which get give me a response when I test controller is okay right? So how to change the mock MondayModel function is necessary?